# Where are the translations in cucumber/gherkin?

Tags: internationalization, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, gherkin

I want to translate this Gherkin scenario in french.

```
Feature: Test the validation on the person object

  Background:
    Given the language is 'english'

  Scenario: Create a person with firstName empty and check we have a violation error message on it
    Given we create a new person
    And we set firstName ''
    And we set lastName 'smith'
    When we apply validation
    Then we should have 1 violation
    And we should have a  error message on 'firstName' that says 'may not be empty'
```

But I don't see where is the translation for Background, and I found (by chance) that the annotation in Java @Etantdonné (similar to @Given) is actually used in the feature file with a space : "Etant donné".

I can't find in the cucumber site documentation on this point.

Can someone give me a link to find out how to use i18n in cucumber/gherkin ?

Answer (score 4):

### To see Listing of available languages

```
> cucumber --i18n help
```

#### Listing the keywords of a particular language

```
> cucumber --i18n <language_code>

> cucumber --i18n fr
```

> for Java, you'll need a full command line: 
>   `java -cp "jars/*" cucumber.api.cli.Main --i18n fr`
>   (where "jars/*" is the folder that your Cucumber/Gherkin jars are located)

#### Header in Feature File

Keep in mind that any language different from `en` should be explicitly marked with a `# language: ...` comment at the beginning of your `*.feature file`:

Example:

```
# language: fr
**Fonctionnalité: ...**
...
```

for French. If you omit this header, Cucumber will default to English `(en)`.

> This way your features will hold all the information about its content type, which is very important for methodologies like BDD and also gives `Cucumber` the ability to have multilanguage features in one suite.

## All gherkins word has been translated

#### For instance in french:

- Scenario - `Scénario`
- Scenario Outline - `Plan du scénario or Plan du Scénario`
- Then - `Alors`
- When - `Quand`
- AND - `Et que`
- BUT - `Mais que`

and so on ...

#### Cucumber JSON data for Language

**You can find all translation of Gherkin here**: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin3/blob/master/gherkin-languages.json

#### JSON data for French Language

```
fr: {
and: [
"* ",
"Et que ",
"Et qu'",
"Et "
],
background: [
"Contexte"
],
but: [
"* ",
"Mais que ",
"Mais qu'",
"Mais "
],
examples: [
"Exemples"
],
feature: [
"Fonctionnalité"
],
given: [
"* ",
"Soit ",
"Etant donné que ",
"Etant donné qu'",
"Etant donné ",
"Etant donnée ",
"Etant donnés ",
"Etant données ",
"Étant donné que ",
"Étant donné qu'",
"Étant donné ",
"Étant donnée ",
"Étant donnés ",
"Étant données "
],
name: "French",
native: "français",
scenario: [
"Scénario"
],
scenarioOutline: [
"Plan du scénario",
"Plan du Scénario"
],
then: [
"* ",
"Alors "
],
when: [
"* ",
"Quand ",
"Lorsque ",
"Lorsqu'"
]
},
```

Hope it will help you...

Comment: Of course, for Java, you'll need a full command line:
    java -cp "jars/*" cucumber.api.cli.Main --i18n fr
(where "jars/*" is the folder that your Cucumber/Gherkin jars are located)

Comment: just perfect, thank you. I put your answer on the [wiki of cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Translations)

Comment: @MichaelCourcy., Great!! How to do that?

Comment: With your github account just go on the project and create a page on the wiki.

Comment: Dear @MichaelCourcy, I have modified Cucumber wiki. Check now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your gherkin in french, you just have to write `# language: fr` at the beginning of the `.feature` file. Link to the doc => https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-feature-files.html#steps-another-lag